# how to send a stream to another object?

Tags: java, file, oop, parsing, java-stream

How do I `stream` each line to the `Parser` instance?

```
package net.bounceme.dur.files;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamFile {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StreamFile.class.getName());
    private Parser p = new Parser();

    public StreamFile() {
    }

    public void read(String filePath) {
        Stream<String> stream = null;
        try {
            stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StreamFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: I suppose there's `getArrayListFromStream(stream); ` but I would want to send each line atomically to myParser.foo(line) somehow.

Comment: `stream.forEach(myParser::foo)`

Comment: You should use the right terminology to explain precisely what you want to do. There is no such thing as “send a stream”. Do you want to invoke a method on the `Parser` instance? Then, include a description of the method in your question.

Comment: yes, and, that being said, the comment by @Code_Mode answers the question for me.  Definitely poorly worded question.